# Preventing multiple clicks from firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, click

Data is loaded dynamically via JSON so I have to use `.on` to load the `.target` and since there are many `targets`, I must do stuff inside the `$.getJSON`, so it has several click handlers.

```
$('.container').on('click', '.target', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.getJSON(myData, function(data, status) {
        $('.another-element').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }

});
```

.... the problem is, when `.another-element` is clicked, it also fires the click event for the `.target` causing all the functions inside it all over again. How do I prevent it?

Comment: Why not move the inner click handler outside? You are anyway using delegation. Register handlers separately

Comment: @ShaunakD cause I'm using the data from the callback, which won't be available outside right?

Comment: It can be made available using plain variable but then the callback would lose its meaning. So I'm not sure what/how the data is accessed or used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `.another-element` is a child of `.target`, stop the propagation with

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

As stated in [**event.stopPropagation()**](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

**Update**

> No, its not a child. A separate element (which is a sibling) is overlayed on top.

You can try checking the targets

```
$('.container').on('click', '.target', function(e) {
    if(e.target.classList.toString().indexOf('target') == -1){
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();

    $.getJSON(myData, function(data, status) {
        $('.another-element').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
            if(e.target.tagName != 'A'){
                return;
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: No, its not a child. A separate element (which is a `sibling`) is overlayed on top.

Comment: I didn't want to do a manual check, but sure, whatever works.